# How to connect given extra two lines in dummy image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

overleaf code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=1.7cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,thick,text width=2.8cm,text centered},node distance=.3cm]
         \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
          \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
           \node[on chain=1](n0) {\scriptsize Training Sequence};
           \node[frm](n1) {\scriptsize cjhj cnnsfjhj chhsd ccnsdjdk cc width and length};
           \node[frm](n2) {\scriptsize jxhhdhj ncjdhasd njshkdjad hdhid  Sequences};
           \node[frm](n3) {\scriptsize bznxd bjksfhkdg sfjkhjaksd hsjkfhr minimum cardinality $m$};
           \node[frm](n4) {\scriptsize kjdhakjdhsf fjkhad (RKP) set Construction};

          \end{scope}
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n1] (n7) {\scriptsize bzdbakjd xbkjdhkdjaxk bkjdhdkjahd xhskjfhdk bckdg};
           \node[boxed,right=.7cm of n2] (n8) {\scriptsize nxzmnankj ncjkhjdhhcjhfsj zxjckahdakj };
           \node at (n0-|n8) (n9) {\scriptsize Test Sequence};
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n3] (n10) {\scriptsize cjhhiuh kdhas input-output frames};
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n4] (n11) {\scriptsize hcjshxhz nzx,mcnls ckjhflsf chcfhrrl RKP};
        %   \node[below=2cm of n10, trapezium,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,
        %     minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,draw,thick] (n14) {\scriptsize Final class};
         \end{scope}

          \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw,-latex,thick}]
           \path
        %   (n1) edge (n8)
        %   \draw [arrow] (nm) |- (pro1);
           (n9) edge (n7)
           (n7) edge (n8)
           (n10) edge (n8)
           (n4) edge (n11)
           (n11) edge (n10);
        %   (n11.north-|n10) edge (n10);
        %   ([xshift=-2mm]n10.south east) coordinate(aux) edge (n14.north-|aux);
          \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Block diagram of the proposed gait recognition approach}
    \label{fig:block11}
\end{figure}
```

output of above code:[image]

Desired output with tow extra lines: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum
        width=1.7cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,thick,text width=2.8cm,text
        centered,font=\scriptsize },node distance=.3cm]
         \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
          \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
           \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training Sequence};
           \node[frm](n1) {cjhj cnnsfjhj chhsd ccnsdjdk cc width and length};
           \node[frm](n2) {jxhhdhj ncjdhasd njshkdjad hdhid  Sequences};
           \node[frm](n3) {bznxd bjksfhkdg sfjkhjaksd hsjkfhr minimum cardinality $m$};
           \node[frm](n4) {kjdhakjdhsf fjkhad (RKP) set Construction};

          \end{scope}
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n1] (n7) {bzdbakjd xbkjdhkdjaxk bkjdhdkjahd xhskjfhdk bckdg};
           \node[boxed,right=.7cm of n2] (n8) {nxzmnankj ncjkhjdhhcjhfsj zxjckahdakj };
           \node at (n0-|n8) (n9) {Test Sequence};
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n3] (n10) {cjhhiuh kdhas input-output frames};
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n4] (n11) {hcjshxhz nzx,mcnls ckjhflsf chcfhrrl RKP};
        %   \node[below=2cm of n10, trapezium,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,
        %     minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,draw,thick] (n14) {\scriptsize Final class};
         \end{scope}

          \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw,-latex,thick}]
           \path
           (n9) edge (n7)
           (n7) edge (n8)
           (n10) edge (n8)
           (n4) edge (n11)
           (n11) edge (n10);
          \draw[draw,-latex,thick] (n1.east) -| 
            ($(n1.east)!0.6!(n8.west)$) |- (n8.west);
          \draw[draw,-latex,thick] ([yshift=-1ex]n1.east) -| 
            ($(n1.east)!0.4!(n11.west)$) |- ([yshift=1ex]n11.west);
          \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Block diagram of the proposed gait recognition approach}
    \label{fig:block11}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much